# DG408 Multiplexer Issue

Tags: microcontroller, multiplexer, load-cell

I connected a DG408 8:1 Multiplexer to 6 Futek Load Cells; the signal of each load cell was amplified by an "ICA-1H" strain gauge amplifier. The output signal of the multiplexer was connected to an analog input port on the NI MyRio; however, when I tested the circuit, the reading displayed from the wrong channel. For example, when I applied force to the load cell at Channel 1, the measurement was output from the indicator of Channel 2. I've checked my LabVIEW code, and everything looks good. The attachment is my circuit schematic. Was there any mistake in my circuit design?  [image]

Comment: what makes you think that there is a mistake in the circuit?

Comment: Because there isn't any mistake in my code...

Comment: famous last words

Comment: Have you verified the correct address is applied to A0..A2?

Comment: Anything to do with the fact that the 408 numbers the channels 1-based (ie 1-8), but software types like their arrays 0 based (0-7)? As the joke goes, there are 2 big problems with software, naming things, cache invalidation, and off-by-one errors.